# call function with raw_input list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to directly input `raw_input` using the least amount of lines possible(without extra variables and whatever) and call the function with it.  The problem is, I need a list.  I am quite aware of the split function, however

```
histogram(split.raw_input("List, sire: "))
```

throws naming errors.  I didn't think it would work, but I thought I'd try anyway.  I'm sure the python gods know how, I've seen pretty ridiculous "pythonic" stuff or whatever it is you call it, but unfortunately I'm not that advanced yet.

Edit: I suppose I should add the rest of my code, but it is most likely entirely irrelevant.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def histogram(x):
    for i in x:
        print int(i) * "*"
```

Referrals to advanced/long reading is appreciated, I'd like to try to soak in as much as I can.

Thanks, got it working.

Comment: It is `raw_input().split("what to split by")`

Comment: What are you trying to split the input by? Ex: commas, spaces, etc. Show us an example input for the `raw_input`

Comment: I'm trying to split it by simple commas, so "1 3 5" turns into ["1","3","5"] and then I can later change to int().

Comment: You mean you are trying to split the spaces. The code for this is `raw_input("String here").split(" ")` to produce a list of the space separated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any modules, this is how it's done:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def string_len(x):
    for i in x:
        print int(i) * "*"

string_len(raw_input("String here").split())
```

Or, completely replace any occurrence of `string_len` with histogram.